# Android PESDK - How to implement a WeatherProvider?

Tags: android, weather, imglykit

In order to use weather based smart stickers I need to add in a `WeatherProvider` object. In iOs it seems that there is a predefined class called `OpenWeatherProvider` that they can use, however Android seems to be less lucky. I tried taking a look at the `WeatherProvider` abstract class, but all I can find is a couple of abstract methods - `onStart()` and `onStop()` which are both `void`; this isn't particularly descrpitive.

Has anyone implemented this functionality, and if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for an answer to this as well